# Matlab Coder/Code Generation -- Array Size Mismatch

Tags: matlab

I have the following functioning code (not my own) that I am attempting to put through C++ code generation.

```
exampleData = double(dataRight(:,2)) < (pointsRight(1,2) + objLength + 0.101);
```

The right side of the expression fails, however, citing a size mismatch between the left and right side of the less than sign.

```
Size mismatch (size [:? x 1] ~= size [0 x 0]).
```

However, matlab's website says that mismatch sizes are, in this case, [the typical use case](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/le.html). Further, no specific exceptions or oddities are noted for Matlab Coder, so I'm a bit lost why I'm getting this error.

Comment: could you share a dump on `pointsRight` ?
have you actually tried this? as far as i know, mismatch size error is when you want to access non-existing row-column..

Comment: [0.051759680404457,0.01,0.0784]. The code runs fine outside of coder's attempt to convert it. Additionally, `test = (pointsRight(1,2) + objLength + 0.101)` runs fine. It is specifically the introduction of `<` that causes the error.

Comment: ah i see..
so basically the trouble is `(pointsRight(1,2) + objLength + 0.101)` scalar (only had a single element), while `double(dataRight(:,2))` could have more than a single element (multiple rows)..

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Is this a coder-specific restriction? `A = [5,4,3]; B= A > 4` works, outside of coder. It yields [1,0,0].

Comment: hmm, i  get your point. it is indeed weird. i think it is the limitation of C++ code generation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a bug/feature request of the MATLAB code generator.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short: you must implement a c-style workaround yourself. I believe what caused by issue is the unbounded size of the array, above. I solved this with size(array) and a for loop.

This is the problem code:

```
dataRight = dataRight(double(dataRight(:,2))>pointsRight(1,2)+0.099 & double(dataRight(:,2))<pointsRight(1,2)+objLength + 0.101,:);
```

Here is the code that coder accepted:

```
[widthDataRight,heightDataRight]= size(dataRight)
tempDataRight = zeros(widthDataRight,heightDataRight)
for i = 1:widthDataRight
     val = dataRight(i,2)
     tempDataRight = dataRight(double(val)>pointsRight(1,2)+0.099 & double(val)<pointsRight(1,2)+objLength + 0.101,:);
end
```